# NextJS 13 and client component callback function prop

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Let's imagine I have a requirement to create a `Table` React component with server-side pagination and sorting functionality, and this component should be reusable in different views and display different types of data.

In `create-react-app` I would write a component that would accept a callback function as a property. This way the parent component will be responsible for re-loading the data and passing it down to the `Table` component.

```
const Table: React.FC<TableProps> = ({ [...], onSortChange }) => {
  [...]

  useEffect(() => onSortChange(sortModel), [sortModel]);
}
```

When I am trying to do something similar in NextJS 13 I end up with having a client component ("use client", because of the fact that I am using the MUI's `DataGrid` and React's `useState`) and a warning:

> TS71007: Props must be serializable for components in the "use client" entry file, "onSortChange" is invalid.

Please, help to understand, what approach should I use instead to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing a function prop to your table component, you could pass an endpoint URL or a key that maps to an API endpoint. The table component can then make a fetch request to that endpoint whenever it needs to reload the data. This way, the table component remains reusable, and the server-side logic for pagination and sorting can still reside on the server.

```
const Table: React.FC<TableProps> = ({ apiEndpoint }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [sortModel, setSortModel] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(apiEndpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ sortModel })
      });

      const result = await response.json();
      setData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [sortModel, apiEndpoint]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer with passing "apiEndpoint" does not use the full potential of the current version of React/Next.js (14+) with server actions and RSC.

There are two potential issues:

1. unnecessary used "use client" in nested client components as described here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/46795#discussioncomment-5248407
2. passing wrong callback from server component to the client component - only server action can be passed

```
// Pages are server components by default
export default async function Page() {
  // some asynchronous server logic
  await getSessionOrRedirect();
  const data = await loadData();

  return (
    <PageClient
      data={data}
      callback={async () => {
        // With this line we pass a valid server action callback
        "use server";

        console.log("called");
        revalidatePath("/");
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

```
// We are changing boundaries, so we need to mark this component as a client
'use client'

export default function PageClient({
  data,
  callback,
}: {
  data: Record<string, string>;
  callback: () => Promise<void>;
}) {
  // In the client component we are allowed to use hooks
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
            callback();
        }}
      >
        Callback
      </button>

      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```